# Getting "XMLHttpRequest" error while using Chrome Web on VS Code

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, xmlhttprequest, chrome-web-driver

When I launch my application on Chrome Web using VS Code and try to send a `http` request to the Backend side, it gives me `XMLHttpRequest error` and does not work.

When I launch the app on Android Emulator it works. Also I tried to add Allow-All-Origins and other CORS options in my Backend application but still I get the same error.

I also tried to deactivate CORS on Chrome Web but it also didn't work. I don't know if is it necessary to add what solutions I tried and didn't get the answer or not, but I also like to know if is it a Bug or a problem with Flutter or Chrome web?

Answer (score 0):

I changed the following line of the code:

```
final url = Uri.parse('http://10.0.2.2:8000/api/$urlSegment');
```

Like below:

```
final url = Uri.parse('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/$urlSegment');
```

And the problem seems to be solved, but I am not sure if it is the correct solution or not?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add code in the header of the backend file.

**add or change in your header code**

"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",

"Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE, HEAD",

Comment: I use Deno backend and it doesn't have such headers I think. It uses `oakcors` and tried it also but didn't work. Finally I changed the requesting address as my answer below and it worked!

Comment: Good. I have also faced the same problem with PHP as backend and I solved using "Access-Control-Allow-Origin".